# SignalR Groups and Users within Groups limitations

Tags: azure, azure-signalr, signalr-service

I'm building a solution with Azure SignalR Service that needs to scale to millions of Groups with tens of thousands of Users within a group.  Are there any limitation on the number of Groups or Users within a Group?

Comment: Doesn't look like there are any documented limits that I can see: [SignalR Service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#signalr-service-limits)

Comment: I haven't found any docs concerning any limitations either.